# jQuery datatable rowgrouping and fixed columns

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatable

I am trying to use jquery rowGrouping as used [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/RgKPZ/).
with Fixed Column plugin as described [here](http://datatables.net/extras/fixedcolumns/)

But I am unable to use it. Can any one give an example of it. I tried to search a lot over the internet but all in vain. Any help is appreciated.

This is how I tried to initiate it:

```
 var tbl = $('#tbl').dataTable({
                    "sScrollY": "300px",
                    "sScrollX": "100%",
                    "sScrollXInner": "150%",
                    "bScrollCollapse": true,                        
                    oLanguage: { sSearch: "" },
                    bPaginate: false,
                    bSort: false
                })
                new FixedColumns( tbl );
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like you forgot to introduce the FixedColumn plugin for DataTables, you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yuuuuc/RgKPZ/163/) for detail

```
var tbl = $('#tbl').dataTable({
                "sScrollY": "300px",
                "sScrollX": "100%",
                "sScrollXInner": "150%",
                "bScrollCollapse": true,                        
                oLanguage: { sSearch: "" },
                bPaginate: false,
                bSort: false
            })
            new FixedColumns( tbl );
```